# Decomposition of the ring of functions on the unipotent radical of a Borel

Tags: algebraic-groups, rt.representation-theory

**Background**

Let $G$ be a semisimple linear algebraic group over an algebraically closed field $k$ of arbitrary characteristic. Let $B \subseteq G$ be a Borel subgroup of $G$ and let $U \subseteq B$ be its unipotent radical. Consider $k[U]$ as a $U$-module under left multiplication in $U$; let's call this module $k[U]_L$. By, say, identifying $U$ with the big cell in the flag variety $G/B^-$, it is not hard to see that $k[U]_L$ is isomorphic as a $U$-module to a direct limit of standard modules $H^0(\lambda)$ for $G$. (In characteristic 0 one can also see this by identifying $k[U]$ with the dual zero Verma module for the enveloping algebra of $G$, cf [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2000-13-04/S0894-0347-00-00347-7/home.html)). In fact there is even a natural ring structure on this direct limit such that this isomorphism is a ring isomorphism.

EDIT: A reference for this fact is Lemma 2.5 and the discussion following it in "[The Nil Hecke Ring and Singularity of Schubert Varieties](http://www.kryakin.com/files/Invent_mat_%282_8%29/123/123_06.pdf)," by Shrawan Kumar. Although the construction is done there over $\mathbb C$, it works over any algebraically closed field, and although Kumar only proves that there is a $T$-equivariant morphism, it is easy to check that the morphism he constructs is $U$-equivariant.

**Question**

Now consider $k[U]$ as a $U$-module under the *conjugation* action of $U$ on itself; let's call this module $k[U]_C$. Is there a nice description of $k[U]_C$ as a $U$-module in terms of $G$-modules in a way analogous to the description of $k[U]_L$?

Comment: The all-purpose explanation "it is not hard to see" could use a reference here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably hard to give a complete description. A lot of partial information about this is contained in this paper of Kostant https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.4494
(in particular there is a description of the subring of invariant elements in $k[U]$;
in fact Kostant works with the Lie algebra of $U$ instead of $U$ itself, but clearly
they are isomorphic as $U$-varieties with respect to the adjoint action).

Answer (score 1):

At first sight it's unclear how much the question has to do with the ambient semisimple group $G$: consider the simplest case when the rank is 1 and $U$ is just the additive group.   It's true that the conjugation action of $G$ itself on its function algebra has a rich structure.    This was shown in characteristic 0 by Kostant and then in a more algebraic setting by Richardson, after which Steve Donkin (Invent. Math. 91, 1988) generalized their results to almost all prime characteristics; his paper is freely available online at

http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002104814

The maximal unipotent subgroup $U$ plays an essential role in the study of a semisimple group, but as a variety it just has the structure of an affine space.    So its actions on its own functions won't provide direct information related to the representations of $G$.

ADDED: The answer to the question as stated is no, based on the rank 1 case where there is no useful connection between the (trivial) conjugation action of $U$ and the representation theory of $G$.   Even with the added references, I haven't been able to figure out what is really being asked in this smallest case.  It would help to start with a more explicit formulation when $G = SL_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments; perhaps this is another way of stating my question: The structure of $k[U]_L$ as a $U$-module can be fruitfully analyzed by a construction involving $G$-modules, so can a similar thing be done to understand $k[U]_C$? In fact the paper of Joseph that I link to above shows that $k[U]_L$ even has the structure of a module for the hyperalgebra of $G$ compatible with the $U$-module structure (the dual zero Verma structure), although I don't expect such a thing occurs for $k[U]_C$.
(cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) In the case of $SL_2$, the construction of Kumar shows that each standard module for $G$ (which in this case is just characterized by its dimension) occurs naturally as a $U$-submodule of $k[U]_L$. I would like to know if something equally nice happens for $k[U]_C$.

Comment: Look at Kostant's paper that I mentioned above - he does exactly what you want for the $U$-invariants in $k[U]_C$.